# Transitive Relation?

Tags: graph-theory, relations

For the graph below

[image]

Is the relation stated below transitive?

> {(u, v) | there is an even path that contains the vertices u, v}

I believe it is as I can not find any counterexamples but want to double check.

Also I am thinking of the path `(1,{1,5},5,{5,2},2)` covering all occurrences of the vertices (1,5,2)
and `(5,{5,2},2,{2,6},6)` for the rest.

Comment: The graph is a single path of length 4, so every pair is in the relation.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen so the relation is transitive yes?

Comment: Yes: transitivity says that if $(u,v)$ and $(v,w)$ are in the relation, then so is $(u,w)$. And because all tuples are in the relation, this always hold.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen thank you !

Comment: @SimonMarynissen the graph is a path, in fact it contains a triangle!